# MVC 5 Error The controller for path '/setpassword' was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, error-handling, controller

I would to like to know how take control of this error, when I want to redirect to the view error bien the html code isn't rendered , so when I try type this  http://localhost:5455/ControllerNotFound, but instead I type http://localhost:5455/Controller/Whatever it's work well.

[No rendering ErrorPage when controller NotFound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9WVW.png)

[Erorr page is Showup when action is NotFound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcmsp.png)

Application Error handler in Global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        brMessaging.Util ObjbsUtil = new brMessaging.Util();
        brMessaging.LogError ObjbsLogError = new brMessaging.LogError();
        try
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

            if (exception != null)
            {
                Server.ClearError();

                var routeData = new RouteData();
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "ErrorHandler");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
                routeData.Values.Add("exception", exception);

                if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
                {
                    routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode());
                }
                else
                {
                    routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
                    var inputData = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"IP: ", ObjbsUtil.getUserIp(Request) } };
                    ObjbsLogError.InsertLog(new SystemFramework.Entities.SFException(exception, 0, "Global", "Application_Error", (int)SystemFramework.Enumerator.PortalName.OV_Messaging,
                    false, Request.Url.ToString(), "Error capturado en el Global.asax", 0, inputData));
                }

                IController controller = new ErrorHandlerController();
                controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try https://es.stackoverflow.com/ instead?

Comment: @tk421 fixed english comments, I hope you could help me

Comment: You might want to look at [MVC 5 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384221/mvc-5-error-handling-web-config-customerrors/40384793#40384793).